# android eclipse adding folder to project

Tags: android, eclipse, directory

i have an android project which has a lot of classes I've built.
i want to organize it to sub folders and my package in eclipse.
when i'm adding a folder and move files over there, what changes should i do in the code so the file which need this classes can reference to it?

is it something in the:

```
import android.app_name.folder_name.class_name
```

help will be appreciated, my project is beginning to be a big mass..

if its not possible i will be glad to hear about other solution

Comment: eclipse had an option when you move your files it will automatically refactor your package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse has a rename/refactor method you can use. The only issue I'm familiar with is the fact that it seems to break the manifest.xml

Comment: how to "unbreak" it then?

Comment: Manually open the file, and fix any issues like referencing files that do not exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import project into Eclipse...

Then you should create a **Package** to manage related classes. (FYI, package is ultimately creates folder hierarchy on your drive).

**Note:** Make sure you provide a correct reference of the particular class in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: my question was how to add sub folder to my project from organizing reasons